# Oracle DBMS SCHEDULER - Email notification for job is not working

Tags: oracle, email, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Oracle version 11.2.0.1.0.

I have created job using dbms scheduler as below,

```
DECLARE
    v_job_name VARCHAR2(5) := SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.GENERATE_JOB_NAME(prefix =>  'JOB'); 
BEGIN
    SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job(
        job_name            =>  v_job_name,
        job_type            =>  'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action          =>  'PKG_TEST.PROCEDURE_TEST;',
        start_date          =>  SYSDATE,
        enabled             =>  TRUE,
        repeat_interval     =>  'freq=minutely; interval=2',
        auto_drop           =>  FALSE,
        comments            =>  'Scheduler Test'        
    );
    SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Name is: ' || v_job_name);
END;
```

Next, configured email notification and SMTP server for above job as below,

```
EXEC SYS.dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server','XXXX.office365.com:XXX');
/
EXEC SYS.dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server_encryption','XXXXXX');
/
EXEC SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_credential (credential_name  => 'MAILSERVER_CREDENTIAL',
                                                username        => 'XXXXX@XXXXXX.com',
                                                password        => 'XXXXXX');
/
EXEC SYS.dbms_scheduler.set_scheduler_attribute('email_server_credential','MAILSERVER_CREDENTIAL');
/
EXEC SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.ADD_JOB_EMAIL_NOTIFICATION (
    job_name            =>  'JOB52',
    recipients          =>  'XXXXX@XXXXX.com',
    sender              =>  'XXXXX@XXXX.com.XX',
    subject             =>  'Oracle Scheduler Job Notification - %job_owner%.%job_name%.%job_subname% %event_type%',
    body                =>  'Job: %job_owner%.%job_name%.%job_subname%
                            Event: %event_type%
                            Date: %event_timestamp%
                            Log id: %log_id%
                            Job class: %job_class_name%
                            Run count: %run_count%
                            Failure count: %failure_count%
                            Retry count: %retry_count%
                            Error code: %error_code%
                            Error message: %error_message%',
    events              =>  'JOB_ALL_EVENTS',
    filter_condition    =>  NULL);
```

Checked table DBA_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS, job run as per schedule.

Checked table DBA_SCHEDULER_NOTIFICATIONS, email notification associated with above job.

Job is running, but I don't get email notification.

I have checked SMTP server and credentials using third party application and email triggered. So SMTP and credentials are correct.

Something goes wrong in it. I searched internet and referred Oracle doc, but no idea what cause the issue.

Is there way to check email log or cause..?

Advice me to sort out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Even though your JOB has successfully run, its possible that your email didn't deliver correctly. This might be due to firewall rules which are often set up to protect database servers. So, please check whether you can actually initiate an email from the database server itself. 
Log on to DB server via SSH and execute the following command to check that. Make sure to replace the SMTP details before executing. If it is failed, then check the reason at network level.

```
curl -v --url 'smtps://smtp.gmail.com:465' --ssl-reqd \
  --mail-from 'XXXXXX@gmail.com' --mail-rcpt 'XXXXX@gmail.com' \
  --user 'XXXXXX@gmail.com:PASSWORD' \
  --upload-file mail.txt
```

***mail.txt is the content of the mail that you want to send.***

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is whether the job is running without error:

```
SELECT * FROM all_scheduler_job_run_details WHERE job_name = 'JOB52';
```

**Edit:**

I'm not aware of any email log. You might try try tracing your session. Also, it looks like you're hitting office365.com as your email server, which might not be accepting connections from your server?

Comment: Yes, Job running without error. STATUS = SUCCESS for that job.

Comment: Job is running. But didn't get email notification.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the events for the job.

```
SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.SET_ATTRIBUTE
    ( name      => 'BANINST1.UH_DISABLE_GUAGMNU_BAN8'
     ,attribute => 'RAISE_EVENTS'
     ,value     => SYS.DBMS_SCHEDULER.JOB_ALL_EVENTS);
```